# how to get for each date in the database the data of max date so far

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database the keeps track of the state of certain process that is either f, s,or p

**Every day** the state of the process may change or stay as it is , but only a new entry will be added to the data base if the state changes 
for example the DB initially contains 4 entries as follows:

```
process_id  state    Day
p1             f      23/9
p2             f      23/9
p3             p      23/9
p4             s      23/9
```

and if on the next day the state of p2 changes from f to p
then a new entry with new date and new status will be added for p2 to the table so the final entries of the DB will be as follows

```
process_id  state     Day
p1             f      23/9
p2             f      23/9
p3             p      23/9
p4             s      23/9
p2             p      24/9
```

what I need to do is to get the count of each state for every day as follows

```
#f     #s    #p     Day
2       1     1     23/9
1       1     2     24/9
```

how can I do this without having to keep duplicate entries with the new Date for the unchanged processes

if I do something like

```
select count(process_id) from my_table group by state,Day
```

this will count only the changed data on 24/9 with no regard to the unchanged data on previous dates knowing that the update occurs daily and entries/day may be little so duplication of data with new dates will be huge and inefficient

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your table to have a start/end date and only insert new rows when there is a change. Example:

```
process_id  state     SDay      EDay
p1             f      23/9      NULL
p2             f      23/9      24/9
p3             p      23/9      NULL
p4             s      23/9      NULL
p2             p      24/9      NULL
```

On 23/9, your P2 changed from f to p. So, put an EDay in of the day it changed, and a start for the new row would equal the end day of the previous one.

Current records would always have a NULL end date. You could also use a future date instead of NULL if you like. Such as: 1/1/2500. That way anytime you wanted just current records, you could say,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Date BETWEEN SDay AND EDay
```

For the second part of your requirement:

> "what I need to do is to get the count of each state for every day"

I would suggest a date dimension table of some sort. Such as:

```
Date
23/5
23/6
23/7
23/8
24/9
...
```

Then, you could:

```
SELECT  count(process_id), state, Date
FROM DateTable
INNER JOIN my_table 
    ON Date BETWEEN SDay AND IFNULL(EDay, '1/1/2500')
GROUP BY state, Date
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :D